# Associating tables in PHP + MySql

Tags: php, mysql

So, i'm creating a money management system. 
My database has 2 tables: main(id,timestamp,value1,value2) and fields(value1,value2).

Value1 and value2 are the categories in which the money are spent. In fact, the script display a table where the rows are the days and the columns are the fields where the money have been spent into (sport, work, girlfriend, etc).

Now, i have a problem. The main query is this:

```
SELECT * FROM main WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, '%M %Y') = '$date' ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

as you see, i extract data only from the main table. So if i wanna list all the categories contents i have to write manually the category name for each one of them, like this:

```
echo "<td>".$row['value'] ."€</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['value2'] ."€</td>";
```

Is there any way it could list all the category name (showing the category content) automatically?

Comment: You need to provide a bit more info, it's quite unclear now what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have a table like this:

  Day |value1|value2|
---------------------
1 Jan | 32€  | 44€  |
---------------------
2 jan | 34€  | 67€  | 

What's the query to take the value1,value2 content AND the fields names (value1,value2) (which are stored in different tables)?

Instead of typing manually  echo "<td>".$row['value1'] ."€</td>"; for each category, i want to take all the category names from a specified table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to cycle through the $row array?

```
foreach ($row as $content) {
    echo "<td>$content €</td>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood what you want... you want to group your expendings by category, correct? I didn't understand how is the relation is done on your two tables so I can't help on you on the SQL statement you are looking for, you need to explain it better, but what you are looking for are something very special in SQL, called `JOIN`s.

Here is a good website with examples: http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p5.php

Hope I've helped